# Delete an entire row in an excel file using Python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am currently using `work_sheet.delete_rows()` using `openpyxl` module, but it only seems to delete the values in the row not the actual row itself..
How can I delete the entire row ??

**This is the actual Excel Data I am currently accessing..**

[image]

**This is now the output after deleting the rows.. The process only deletes the values of each rows not the entire row itself...**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing there's something wrong with the way you're calling it. While you've stated what you're using, you haven't given us the actual *code* that you're using.

The actual [source code](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html#Worksheet.delete_rows) for `OpenPyXl` shows that it does actually move the rows below the area being deleted up to the start of that area.

You can actually see this by using the following simple spreadsheet:

```
      A       B
--+-------+-------+
1 |   1   |   a   |
2 |   3   |   b   |
3 |   5   |   c   |
4 |   7   |   d   |
5 |   9   |   e   |
```

The following script shows the deletion of the second, third, and fourth row:

```
import openpyxl

def dumpWs(desc, ws):
    print(f'{desc}: ', end = '')
    for row in ws.values:
        print(end = '<')
        sep = ''
        for value in row:
            print(f'{sep}{value}', end = '')
            sep = ', '
        print(end = '> ')
    print()

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('version1.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
dumpWs('As loaded   ', ws)

ws.delete_rows(2, 3)
dumpWs('After delete', ws)

wb.save('version2.xlsx')
```

Running this script results in:

```
As loaded   : <1, a> <3, b> <5, c> <7, d> <9, e> 
After delete: <1, a> <9, e>
```

The version saved with the `wb.save` line is as expected:

```
      A       B
--+-------+-------+
1 |   1   |   a   |
5 |   9   |   e   |
```

---

One thing you *may* want to check is the version of `OpenPyXl` that you're using, since there are several bug reports on various iterations of `delete_rows`. I'm using version `3.0.3` (with Python `3.6.8`, for completeness).

Comment: so it actually deletes the row not only the values?
but still I got it already, Thanks for the response..
what I am trying to point out is that values are really being deleted in the excel file, but the row isn't..
so everytime I loop in the rows of that excel file, the loop still counts the row but the value is already deleted...

Comment: @IAmArien: how are you iterating over the rows? You can see by my code that it's freshly evaluating the row count after deletion, with `for row in ws.values`. If your code is somehow remembering the previous row count, that would explain the discepency. If you want to ask a new question showing your actual code being used, I'll give some further help with that possibility ...

Comment: thank you for that @paxdiablo... I have edited my question for further clarifications of what I am trying to point out..
can you help me with that?

also the excel file must be in the same excel file, we can save it in another version like what you have stated in your answer but in my code, I have to use and save to same excel file...
thanks for consideration.